# Combine php syntax with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have code like this :

```
 $.each(data.step_2, function (i, item) {
   var date_php = '<?= strftime('%A, %d %b %Y',strtotime("2016-11-22")); ?>'; //i want change it
   var arr = item.arrival_time === null ? '-' : item.arrival_time;
   trHTML += '<tr><td>' + date_php + '</td><td>' + item.departure_time + 
             '</td><td>' + arr + '</td><td><input type="radio" name="pilihan" id="pilihan" value="' 
             + item.schedule_id +'"></td></tr>'; 
     // item.schedule_date 
});
```

I want change " `strtotime("2016-11-22"));` " with `strtotime("item.schedule_date"));` that "`item.schedule_date`" i get from ajax data.

How to combine it?

Comment: Where is your work on getting the data through ajax?

Comment: You need to do this in javascript which runs in the browser long after php has done it's work on the server

Comment: You can perform strtotime after the success clause of you ajax call. To successfully get the value I believe you need not put double quotes on the targeted variable. Like so, strtotime(item.schedule_date)

Comment: @KentAguilar there is no access to `strtotime()` in the browser only on server

Comment: Oh yeah, then we could perform the strtotime on the php endpoint prior to the ajax call. the formatting will be on the server side. client side will be for display only.

Comment: I have resolve it by create ajax that call php function to process "item.schedule_date" and return it with " strftime('%A, %d %b %Y',strtotime("2016-11-22")); " format.

Another quetion, it's "possible" to combine php syntax with ajax?

Answer (score 0):

In javascript to use **strftime** you must use an external javascript library. For example i used following library :   http://hacks.bluesmoon.info/strftime/demo.html (download this script to include into your development server)

Here is my code :

```
<script src="http://hacks.bluesmoon.info/strftime/strftime.js"></script>
<script>
    var date_php = '<?= strftime('%A, %d %b %Y',strtotime("2016-11-22")); ?>';
    alert(date_php);   //converted using php

    var d = new Date("2016-11-22");
    var ymd = d.strftime('%A, %d %b %Y');
    alert(ymd);  //converted using javascript
</script>
```

Comment: yup this work, but how if i have other case that should used php syntax in ajax? I need to know how to combine it

Comment: You can use other formats too given in demo url. Or you can use moment.js

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.each(data.step_2, function (i, item) {
   var date_php = '<?= strftime('%A, %d %b %Y',strtotime("'+item.schedule_date+'")); ?>'; //i want change it
   var arr = item.arrival_time === null ? '-' : item.arrival_time;
   trHTML += '<tr><td>' + date_php + '</td><td>' + item.departure_time + 
             '</td><td>' + arr + '</td><td><input type="radio" name="pilihan" id="pilihan" value="' 
             + item.schedule_id +'"></td></tr>'; 
     // item.schedule_date 
});
```

considering the `item.schedule_date` returns the date like `2016-11-22`
check once and the main thing is the php code runs if the js is in the same template file not external lib

Comment: it's in php file, and item.schedule_date also have value like "Y-m-d"

Comment: use source code ctrl + u if u see date instead of <?= strftime('%A, %d %b %Y',strtotime("'+item.schedule_date+'")); ?> this will work